# How to write a value to the workflow container

Tags: workflow, abap

Below is my workflow inbox content

[image]

**STEP 1:** ln HTML table, the user can approve or reject WBS by checked radio

**STEP 2:** When user click confirm, then the workflow will update status for each WBS that shown in the table.

**Purpose:**
I need to get the user's action from step 1.

For now I've enhanced SAPEVENT and make it called my Function Module.

In my function function module I can use 'SAP_WAPI_READ_CONTAINER' properly but **I cannot use 'SAP_WAPI_WRITE_CONTAINER' to write the value to workflow**.

**There was error msg 900  occurs.**

Please see my code below:

```
        DATA: LT_CONTAINER TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF SWR_CONT,
        LT_MSG_LINES TYPE SAPI_MSG_LINES,
        LT_MSG_STRUC TYPE SAPI_MSG_STRUC.
            
        DATA: LV_RETCODE TYPE SY-SUBRC.
            
        *** Get workflow container by using 'SAP_WAPI_READ_CONTAINER' ***    
    
        CALL FUNCTION 'SAP_WAPI_READ_CONTAINER'
            EXPORTING
                WORKITEM_ID      = IV_WORKITEMID
            IMPORTING
                RETURN_CODE      = LV_RETCODE
            TABLES
                SIMPLE_CONTAINER = LT_CONTAINER
                MESSAGE_LINES    = LT_MSG_LINES
                MESSAGE_STRUCT   = LT_MSG_STRUC.
        
        *** then I change data inside LT_CONTAINER as my requirement below ***
    
    
        REPLACE |type="submit" id="ALLAPPV"| IN TABLE LT_CONTAINER[] 
        WITH |type="button" id="ALLAPPV" hidden|.
    
    
        *** use SAP_WAPI_WRITE_CONTAINER in order to write value to workflow container but it return error msg 900 ***
        
        CALL FUNCTION 'SAP_WAPI_WRITE_CONTAINER'
            EXPORTING
                WORKITEM_ID                  = IV_WORKITEMID
                DO_COMMIT                    = 'X'
                OVERWRITE_TABLES_SIMPLE_CONT = 'X'
            IMPORTING
                RETURN_CODE                  = LV_RETCODE
            TABLES
                SIMPLE_CONTAINER             = LT_CONTAINER
                MESSAGE_LINES                = LT_MSG_LINES
                MESSAGE_STRUCT               = LT_MSG_STRUC.
```

Comment: I've got no issue at my side, SAP_WAPI_WRITE_CONTAINER updates perfectly a multi-line element of type SOLI, it returns RETURN_CODE = 0, MESSAGE_LINES = "Container successfully written", MESSAGE_STRUCT = WZ S 520. What message do you get?

Comment: In table LT_MSG_LINES - "Cannot call WAPI interface 'SAP_WAPI_WRITE_CONTAINER' in this context"
In table LT_MSG_STRUC - MSGID = SWR, MSGTY = E, MSGNO = 209, MSGV1 =  SAP_WAPI_WRITE_CONTAINER

Comment: I guess it's a lock issue while working from within the work item (in the inbox). I found a similar problem [here](https://answers.sap.com/questions/8049236/cannot-call-wapi-interface-%27sapwapiforwardworkitem.html) with explanation from Jocelyn. You can execute it only if you leave the work item dialog. Note that in workflow programming, you don't need to change the container yourself, you create a dialog method whose return parameter is mapped to the container of the standard task and to the workflow step, the work item container will automatically reflect the change.